# How SQL Server knows if my database user can access resources in another database?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sid

I have created two logins: Login1 and Login2, the first one having the sysadmin role.

Then I log in with both of them and find these scenarios:

a. Login1: I can read data in msdb database.
b. Login2: I can't read data in msdb database.

I am interested in knowing the deep reason.

It is related to Login1 and Login2 different permissions, but, the question is how SQL Server internally knows that Login1 has enough privileges to access msdb? How permissions work internally?

Comment: `sysadmin` is a server level role, Not a database role, and the `sysadmin` can do **anything** on the server. As for the other user, if they don't have a user on the msdb database, they will only have permissions that the public role has on MSDB.

Comment: `sysadmin` role members have full permissions to the instance and are automatically the `dbo` user in all databases. Other users must have a user created in the database for the login (unless the database guest user is enabled).